# python requests return a different web page from browser or urllib

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

I use requests to scrape webpage for some content.
When I use

```
import requests  
requests.get('example.org')
```

I get a different page from the one I get when I use my broswer or using

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlopen('example.org')
```

I tried using `urllib` but it was really slow.
In a comparison test I did it  was 50% slower than `requests` !!

How Do you solve this??

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of investigations I found that the site passes a cookie in the header attached to the first visitor to the site only.

so the solution is to get the cookies with `head` request, then resend them with your `get` request

```
import requests  
# get the cookies with head(), this doesn't get the body so it's FAST
cookies = requests.head('example.com')
# send get request with the cookies
result = requests.get('example.com', cookies=cookies)
```

Now It's faster than urllib + the same result :)

Comment: Or you can use a `Session` instance. It will automatically manage cookies for with `CookieJar`.

Comment: I tried that but in my case the cookie was sent with the first request only & I didn't want to reuse the same cookie in subsequent requests, so I simply passed the cookies to the get request.  Still your suggestion valid for most of other cases